# jQuery Animation in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I am trying to attach jQuery `.fadeIn("slow");` with an `append();` in a `forEach();` loop the following way:

```
items.forEach(function (item) {
     showData.append('<div>Test</div>').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

However, as soon as the loop is trigger the amount of div's being added are still not being added with the fade effect. Any ideas of how I can get the fade effect work either via jQuery or CSS whatever is the best solution.

Comment: Really need to show more code for other to answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're animating the `showData` element, whatever that is, and it's probably already visible.
What you wanted was probably to animate the inserted DIV instead

To make the elements appear one after the other, you could use a delay that increases with each iteration

```js
var items  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  showData = $('#test');

items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  $('<div />', {
    text : 'Test',
    css  : {display: 'none'}
  }).delay(index * 600).fadeIn('slow').appendTo(showData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Of course, the element must be hidden before it can be faded in

Comment: Thankyou, how can I add the fadeIn on every div and not all at one go tho ?

Comment: It is adding it on every DIV, I think what you're asking is how do you delay the animations so the elements appear one after the other

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am looking for :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include that

Comment: Thankyou! that works perfectly fine, however instead of one div, I have multiple elements to add, just to give you an idea, `<a style="overflow: hidden;" class="testLink" data-remodal-target="modal"><div class="element-item ' + subcat + '"><img onclick="InfoCard" src="' + item.IMG+ '"/></div></a>` how can I implement this append into the way you explained above.

Comment: You'd create the element, hide the outer element, in that case the anchor, and then append and fade in, something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/pctjzx4x/

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, did you see the fiddlle above

Comment: adeno, yes I seen it, sorry the comment was posted exactly together, I will delete my comment. It is working fine, the on click is the only thing which is not working. I am implementing it this way: `on: {click: InfoCard(item.id)}` however this is not happening

Comment: Nope, that won't work, you have to do either `{click : InfoCard}`  or `{click : function() { InfoCard(item.id) }}`

Comment: Thankyou so much adeneo, it is working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `.fadeIn(...)` on the appended element, you're calling it on the `showData` element.

You can do something like this:

```
items.forEach(function (item) {
    var e = $("<div>Test</div>");
    e.hide();
    showData.append(e);
    e.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 items.forEach(function (item) {
         var div = $('<div>Test</div>').hide();
         showData.append(div);
         div.fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

```js
var i=0;
while(i<10){
var div = $('<div>Test</div>').hide();
$('body').append(div);
div.fadeIn('3000');
i++;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```